# merge multiple columns value of a dataframe into a single column with bracket in middle

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe.

```
category     value    percentage_difference
Cosmetics    789.99   300.0
Fruits       27.68    400.0
Clothes      179.20   500.0
```

I want to add fourth column so that its value is category(value, percentage)

```
category     value    percentage_difference merge_value
Cosmetics    789.99   300.0                 Cosmetic(789.99, 300%)
Fruits       27.68    400.0                 Fruits(27.68, 400%)
Clothes      179.20   500.0                 Clothes(179.20, 500%
```

With for loop I can do, is there any other efficient method without for loop?

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is just add the column as strings:

```
df=df.assign(merge_value=
      df.category+"("+df.value.astype(str)+','+df.percentage_difference.astype(str)+"%)")
print(df)
```

---

```
    category   value  percentage_difference             merge_value
0  Cosmetics  789.99                    300  Cosmetics(789.99,300%)
1     Fruits   27.68                    400      Fruits(27.68,400%)
2    Clothes  179.20                    500     Clothes(179.2,500%)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach using a list comprehension:

```
df['merge_value'] = ['{}({}, {:0}%)'.format(x, y, int(z)) for x, y, z in
                     df[['category', 'value', 'percentage_difference']].values]
```

[out]

```
    category   value  percentage_difference              merge_value
0  Cosmetics  789.99                  300.0  Cosmetics(789.99, 300%)
1     Fruits   27.68                  400.0      Fruits(27.68, 400%)
2    Clothes  179.20                  500.0     Clothes(179.2, 500%)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'category': ['Cosmetics', 'Fruits', 'Clothes'],
                     'value': [789.99,27.68, 179.20],
                    'percentage_difference': [300.0,400.0,500.0]})
df['merge_value'] = df.apply(lambda r: "{0}({1}, {2}%)".format(r['category'], r['value'], r['percentage_difference']), axis=1)
```